# Message body empty in PHPMailer can't figure what is wrong at all

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong but just can't point the finger on it. I am still very new to PHP so it may be a misspell or something really small that someone better experienced would see right away.I have a contact form on my website and I want people to be able to send me emails. Here's the code:

```
<?php
require_once 'libs/phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Mailer = "smtp";
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Username = "****@****.com";
$mail->Password = "*****";
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->FromName = $name;
$mail->AddAddress("*******.com", "*******");
$mail->Body = $body;

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];
$message = $_POST['message'];
$company = $_POST['company'];
$body = "La Personne qui nous contacte est: " . $name . " qui travaille pour: " . $company . " le sujet du message etant: " . $subject . " et le message est: " . $message . " nous pouvons la rejoindre par courriel: " . $email . " ou encore par telephone: " . $phone;

$nameErr = $emailErr = $messageErr = "";
$name = $email = $message = "";

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){
    if(empty($_POST['name'])){
        $nameErr = "Veuillez entrer votre nom.";
    }else{
        $name = test_input($_POST['name']);
        if(!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)){
            $nameErr = "Seulement des lettres et espaces sont permis";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email'])){
        $emailErr = "Addresse courriel requise!";
    }else{
        $email = test_input($_POST['email']);
        if(!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
            $emailErr = "L'addresse courriel n'est pas valide!";
        }
    }
    if(empty($_POST['message'])){
        $messageErr = "* Message Obligatoire!";
    }else{
        $message = test_input($_POST['message']);
    }
}
function test_input($data){
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    return $data;
}

if(isset($_POST['sendmail'])){
if(!$mail->Send()) {
    echo 'Message was not sent.';
    echo 'Mailer error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent.';
}}

?>
```

Basically i have checked the $body value and it echoes as it should. but when i hit the 'sendmail' button it echoes out: Message was not sent.Mailer error: Message body empty. Right before i added the validation part, everything was running fine, except that i could send an empty form. if ever it is needed here is the form:

```
    <form method="post" style="margin-top: 25px;" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Adresse Courriel: <span class="error">* <?php echo $emailErr;?></span></label>
            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="name">Votre Nom: <span class="error">* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span></label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="phone">Votre Telephone:</label>
            <input type="tel" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="company">L'entreprise:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="company" id="company">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="subject">Le Sujet du Message:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message">Votre Message: <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span></label>
            <textarea name="message" class="form-control" id="message" cols="30" rows="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <input style="margin-bottom: 10px;" id="sendmail" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="sendmail" value="Envoyer!">
    </form>
```

I thank anyone who will take a couple minutes checking this out and give me some advice! Please note, I am certainly not a PHP professional, there can be many noob errors and even bad syntax, I am not here to be judged and sentenced, I need help from people better than me!

Comment: You're assigning `$mail->Body` before creating `$body`. Move the `$mail` assignments after your error checking. Or at least after you build `$body`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$mail->Body = $body;
```

Above line should be after adding content to `$body`. So Your code should look something like this,

```
$body = "La Personne qui nous contacte est: " . $name . " qui travaille pour: " . $company . " le sujet du message etant: " . $subject . " et le message est: " . $message . " nous pouvons la rejoindre par courriel: " . $email . " ou encore par telephone: " . $phone;

$mail->Body = $body;
```

You were using `$body` variable before adding content into it.