# PHPMailer error "Message body empty" with Gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer

I am new for PHPMailer and when I have set the code to send an email with PHPMailer it shows me an error with:

> Mailer Error: Message body empty

I have tried many links from stack also like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13816571/phpmailer-mailer-error-message-body-empty) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591244/message-body-empty-in-phpmailer-cant-figure-what-is-wrong-at-all/38591321), but couldn't got the solution.

Below is my code

```
<?php
   // Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
   // These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
   use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

   require 'src/Exception.php';
   require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
   require 'src/SMTP.php';

   //Create a new PHPMailer instance
   $mail = new PHPMailer;
   $mail->isSMTP();
   $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
   $mail->Host = 'abc@test.com';
   $mail->Port = 587;
   $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
   $mail->Username = 'abc@gmail.com';
   $mail->Password = '*****';
   $mail->setFrom('xyz@gmail.com', 'test');
   $mail->addReplyTo('xyz@gmail.com', 'Test');
   $mail->addAddress('example@gmail.com', 'Receiver Name');
   $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer SMTP message';
   $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('message.html'), __DIR__);
   $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain text message body';
   /*$mail->addAttachment('test.txt');*/
   if (!$mail->send()) {
     echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
   } else {
     echo 'Message sent!';
  }
?>
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Try to change `$mail->msgHTML` to `$mail->body`

Comment: it shows me - PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer::body()

Comment: Sorry, there is a typo. `Body` must start with capital B.Try again.

Comment: @MNJ first dump this `file_get_contents('message.html')` and see its working.

Comment: it still shows -  Mailer Error: Message body empty

Answer (score 1):

The call to `msgHTML()` will set both plain and HTML body parts. If your call to `file_get_contents` returns nothing, you will end up with an empty body, which will trigger the error you are seeing.

So check that call first:

```
$body = file_get_contents('message.html');
var_dump($body);
$mail->msgHTML($body, __DIR__);
```

This will still show the error, but you will be able to check your content first. If your file called `message.html` is not empty, check using an absolute path (e.g. by using `__DIR__ . '/message.html'`), and if that still fails to produce a result, check that the user accessing the file has sufficient permissions to do so.

Note that `msgHTML` also sets `AltBody`, so unless you specifically want to override that, you don’t need to set that as well.